# HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure - Not able to Publish Application on Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to publish my .NET Core API application on Azure.
I have a publish profile, i.e, a `.publishsetting` file.
I am also getting the below message on publishing :

Below is the Output when I Publish the Application

> Publish Succeeded.
> Web App was published successfully http://myapplication.azurewebsites.net/
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
> Installation of Web App Site extension Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension is in progress...
> Successfully installed Web App extension Microsoft.AspNetCore.AzureAppServices.SiteExtension
> Restarting the Web App...
> Successfully restarted the Web App.

But when I go to http://myapplication.azurewebsites.net/ this location,
I am getting the below error :

> "HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure".

[image]

How to solve this problem, do I need to configure my IIS for this?

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Yes, I have resolved it.

Comment: Or you can post your solution to the problem as an answer, which can help more forum users.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to locate this problem directly. You can only provide a solution. You follow the steps to try to solve it.

> Step 1. Go to SCM site

> Step 2. Find and change the `web.config` to generate logfiles.

> Step 3. Check logs.

For more details, you can read this offical article.

**[Troubleshooting HTTP 502.5 startup issues in Azure AppService for ASP.NET Core Websites](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/troubleshooting-http-502-5-startup-issues-in-azure-appservice/ba-p/392589)**

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with vault key permissions.
Steps to debug -
Go to App Service in the Azure portal, where you have Url of your application.
in this go-to application logs, in my application log, it was clearly mentioned that it requires permission to read vault keys. I have given permission to this and it started working.

Comment: My answer provides an idea to query the log. There are many reasons for a 500 server error. Congratulations on finding the reason and solving your problem.

Comment: Because of the 500 error, the knowledge involved cannot be determined directly. We need to check the app log to make sure.